# Creating a help icon using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

Right now I am  using an anchor tag to generate a question mark for the help icon. Looks like this

[image]

But I want the question mark to look like this:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how I can style it with CSS to look like the 2nd one. How do you create a background that's 1) a circle and 2) has a gradient?

Comment: I'm not sure why i got downvoted but ok...

Comment: I didn't downvote but its most probably because you haven't added what you have tried so far.

Comment: You're asking for use to find a graphic for you. That isn't a programming problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with css like this.

```css
a {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#feb22a;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">?</a>
```

But Quentin are right that is a graphic problem not a programmer